# Find the variance given the expectation and a probability.

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $Z$ be a random variable, distributed uniformly on $[a,b]$ with $\mathbb{E}(Z) = 11$ and $P(Z < 0) = \frac 2 5$. Find $\mathbb V(Z)$.

I know that the expectation of some random variable $X$ with probability density function $p(x)$ is given by $\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_D x\ dP$. Furthermore, the variance is given by $\mathbb{V}(X) = \int_D x^2\ dP - \mathbb{E}^2$.

I don't actually know how to derive these, but they seem to have the same form of the non-continuous case $\mathbb{E} = \sum v_kP(X=v_k)$ and $\mathbb{V} = \sum v_k^2 P(X=v_k) - \mathbb{E}^2$. However, this intuition doesn't really help me solve this problem. I'm not even entirely sure what the probability value given does to aide.

We haven't learned about Z-ing yet, either, so I imagine that has nothing to do with this... in any case, any assistance would be great.

Comment: i think the idea is from your first sentence, you should be able to figure out $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $\frac{a+b}{2} = 11$ i.e. $a+b = 22$.
You also know that $P(Z<0)=\frac 2 5$. That means $b>0$ and $a<0$. Further it means that $\frac{|a|}{|a|+b} = \frac{-a}{-a+b} = 2/5$.

Solving this system of equations yields $a=-44,b=66$. Then its not hard to find the variance of a known uniform.

Comment: Okay. I did not actually know that $E(X) = \frac{a+b}{2}$, but that makes sense. It follows that $V(X)= \frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$. Thank you.